# Deleting row from UITableView causes section header issues?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader

I have a `UITableView` with custom section headers implemented as `UITableViewCell`s.  The relevant method from my `UITableViewDelegate` looks like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        log.debug("Creating header for section \(section)")
        let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SectionHeaderCell") as! JournalEntrySectionHeaderTableViewCell

        let keys = Array(self.journalEntries.keys.sorted())
        let date = keys[section]

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        let template = "MMMMd, yyyy"

        dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate(template)
        let dateStr = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        headerCell.titleLabel?.text = dateStr

        let theme = ThemeManager.shared.currentTheme()
        headerCell.backgroundColor = theme.entryListHeaderBackgroundColor
        headerCell.titleLabel?.textColor = theme.entryListHeaderTextColor

        return headerCell
    }
```

Everything renders properly, and looks like this:

[image: Properly rendered UITableView]

However, when I go to remove a `UITableViewCell` by calling `self.entryTableView?.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)`, after the animation is performed the section header is not rendered properly.  This is the resulting rendering:

[image: Incorrectly rendered UITableView]

You'll notice in this screenshot that I deleted a row from the March 9, 2019 section.  After doing so, the section header for the March 26, 2019 section is not rendered at all.  If I scroll the table down and then scroll back up, the section headers are rendered properly, as expected.

I've never seen anything like this before, and it does not happen if I remove my custom `viewForHeaderInSection` implementation and simply make use of `titleForHeaderInSection`.  However, that's not an option, because I need to change the background color of the section header to match our UI theme.  Has anyone encountered this before?  Any idea what the issue could be?

Comment: Can you please add code for function where you call `self.entryTableView?.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)`?

Answer (score 0):

I may think there could be 2 potential issue.

1. Could you verify if you remove dataSource element before call

   `self.entryTableView?.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)`
2. `let keys = Array(self.journalEntries.keys.sorted())`

This keys changes after you remove the element? Which's could lead to unexpected behavior.